# How to create mesh collider for a blender model

Tags: mesh, collision

I have built a house model in blender. I want to add collider to it's interior and exterior walls. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, just go to physics tab and apply collision to walls. Or make a secondary box around it and give that collision. This is for blender related stuff. If you are going to export it you need to dig around youtube for a tut.

Comment: Could you please point me to a tutorial for adding the collision to walls? Basically when I export the model to .obj and use it in a-frame, my camera ends up going through wall instead of colliding